# Android, FileNotFound Exception, but found by Glide without problems. What is the problem?

Tags: android, filesystems

Using Glide, the following uri path to a png file is loaded without problems. In Android, the following code results in "file not found exception". Why? What do I need to do with the uri to make it work "everywhere" in Android?

uri = content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A11322, as given by the default file chooser, used programmatically.

```
FileInputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(new File(uri));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
```

Using BitMapFactory.decodeFile(uri) is even worse, since it also gives the same exception because it cannot find the file on the path = content:/com.android…. Important: Note that BitmapFactory removed one of the two slashes, for whatever reason. A bug?

Thanks for any help that can convert this work down from a two day "seek and find" the solution, down to the expected two minute job. Android contains an amazing number of built-in traps, I must say.

Comment: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A11322` is not a file path, you can't create a file from it. It's an `Uri`. You can create InputStream from Uri directly.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open a `FileInputStream` on a content scheme uri.

Open an `InputStream` on the uri instead.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

You can use the stream as before.

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```